# How do I dynamically retrieve columns using the oData source via SSIS?

Tags: dynamic, ssis, odata, metadata

I have several SSIS packages that use oData sources to pull data from SharePoint lists and libraries.  Unfortunately, I'm not always notified when those lists and libraries are changed on the SharePoint server.....

Now, when those packages break, I know how to fix them manually.  That's not a problem.  What I would like to know is whether or not there's any way to dynamically refresh the package and recognize that there's more or less or different columns than there were before.......that way, I don't have to redevelop the package unless/until they need the new columns represented in the SQL Server database....

Comment: How would you expect to handle the new/changed columns? To my knowledge there is no magic pill to handle this type of change. It is no different than someone changing the columns in Excel (happens a lot) and even in a CSV (doesn't happen when system driven). SharePoint users do not need to follow a tech deployment cycle and testing to make Production changes, so they always break things. The solution is to not let them change things and if they don't listen, then their data breaks. It's their problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I work in a toxic office, so the government lead will make it my problem.  How would I expect to handle new/changed columns?  Drop the staging table, create it with the new field list, then ingest the data...  Drop the live table, create it with the new field list, then move the data over.

Comment: Can't you ask for specific columns in oData? Return the columns that you need instead of a select *. If they want the new columns they need to ask for them.

Comment: If I ask for specific columns in oData, will it not break the SSIS package if the SharePoint list's metadata changes? (Adding or deleting columns)....